# When I activate a conda environment in a VS Code terminal, I cannot use the corresponding Python interpreter in the terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, anaconda, conda

System:

```
System Version: macOS 10.15.7 (19H1030)
Kernel Version: Darwin 19.6.0
conda version: 4.10.1
VS Code version: 1.56.2
```

I open the VS Code terminal, create a conda environment and activate it:

```
conda create -n foo python=3.6
conda activate foo
```

I install `pandas` and check that the installation was successful:

```
conda install pandas
conda list pandas
# packages in environment at /opt/anaconda3/envs/foo:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
pandas                    1.1.5            py36hb2f4e1b_0
```

Simple script `test.py` to test that everything is fine:

```
import pandas
print(pandas.__version__)
```

So far, so good. With the `foo` environment still active, I run

```
(foo) ...:~ <username>$ python test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

...Not so good anymore. The issue is that,even though the conda environment is active and the corresponding Python interpreter is selected in VS Code,

[image]

the terminal insists on using the system Python intepreter, for which `pandas` is **not** installed:

```
(foo) ...:~ <username>$ python
WARNING: Python 2.7 is not recommended. 
This version is included in macOS for compatibility with legacy software. 
Future versions of macOS will not include Python 2.7. 
Instead, it is recommended that you transition to using 'python3' from within Terminal.

Python 2.7.16 (default, Jun  5 2020, 22:59:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.29.20) (-macos10.15-objc- on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pandas
>>>
```

Neither `conda init bash`, `conda init` or `source ~/.bash_profile` solved the issue. How can I get VS Code to actually **use** my conda env when running stuff in the terminal? I'm pulling my hair out on this.

PS note that if I use a better Mac terminal emulator (e.g., iTerm2), instead of the VS Code terminal, everything works fine.

```
(foo) ...:~ <username>$ conda activate foo
(foo) ...:~ <username>$ python test.py
1.1.5
```